# How to show label given value in Angular [ng-select]

Tags: angular

I recently used [ng-select](https://github.com/basvandenberg/ng-select) library in my project and it works great. One limitation i found is that the library expects a string to be inputed in order to render the label properly. With that, I realized that I'll have an issue if I want to show the label of an id given that the model only has the id stored.

As oppose to other libraries (which at this point I am not considering since this library answers most of my needs), the id of the element is being stored in the model. Hence in order to show the label somewhere else I need to translate this. This can be costly since I have dozens of catalogs to work with.

Take this example:

```
[{ 'id' : 'A', 'label': 'Apple'},
 { 'id' : 'B', 'label': 'Banana'},
 { 'id' : 'C', 'label': 'Cranberry'}]
```

The model stores:

```
{fruit: 'A'};
```

In order to show the label anywhere I need to translate 'A' to 'Apple' somehow. 
I thought of creating a pipe but then I'll need to do so for each catalog I hold.

Any ideas on how to approach?

Comment: Where is the model data set?

Comment: Good question. The data model is set by the application (in other words I control it). However, the library enforces to store only the ID as a string.

Comment: Still looking for suggestions...

Comment: I ended up creating a service that take in the id and the catalog name to translate the id to the label